# default arguments in function - Python

Tags: python, function, arguments

So, here is a piece of code:

```
def function(item, stuff = []):
    stuff.append(item)
    print stuff

function(1)
# print '[1]'

function(2)
# print '[1,2]'
```

As I understood, this shows, that default values, changed during program run still changed at every function calls. But why this piece of code:

```
def function(item, stuff  = 0):
    stuff  += item
    print stuff  

function(3)
function(3)
```

prints '3' at every runs?

Comment: Looks like `stuff`is re-initialized on every call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lists in Python are *mutable*: They can be modified after they have been created. That's why the `stuff` list grows when you call the first function, it's the same list object each time.

Integers on the other hand are *immutable*. You cannot change them after you have them created. So what this does

```
a = 2
a += 1
```

is to remove the `a` label from the "2" object and attach it to the "3" object instead.

That's why the "0" object (the default value for the `stuff` argument of the second function) remains unchanged and you get 3 everytime.